# Symfony site robots.txt is not accessible

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, robots.txt, google-search-console

I have a Symfony site hosted and recently Google webmaster tools notified that it cannot access robots.txt file. It is in the root but cannot be viewed in browser. It has produced this "New Index coverage issue detected for site http://www.example.com/" error. When I checked I found out that Google cannot access robots.txt. I reuploaded a new sitemap.xml also.

I changed the permission of robots.txt to 777, 775, 755, 644, 664 but still no luck. Also when I create test.txt it's contents are displayed in browser and it is accessible. How can I fix this?

Comment: *"It is in the root but cannot be viewed in browser."* - what happens if you do try and view it in the browser? 403 error? Check that access isn't being blocked in either a root .htaccess file or the <VirtualHost> (if you've got access to httpd-vhosts.conf)...

Comment: This hast nothing to do with permissions. Can you check if the path http://www.example.com/robots.txt is accessible? If not, that's your problem. But that's a problem with your rooting or maybe your robots.txt is not int he `/web` path of your project.

Comment: Any file I put in the root (example.com/) is accessible (viewable) from web browser but only robots.txt is not accessible. Chrome gives "This page isn’t working ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Comment: Sounds like you've got something re-routing robots.txt incorrectly that's causing an infinite loop; check your `RewriteRule`s

Answer (score 2):

Put the robots.txt file in public (for Symfony 4) or web (for Symfony 2 & 3) folder.